# Url django with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this is my url file for my "backend" application.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'gamelogs', views.GameLogViewSet)
router.register(r'referees', views.RefereeViewSet)
router.register(r'players', views.PlayerViewSet)
router.register(r'teams', views.TeamViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'reports/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_pdf_report, name='get_pdf_report'),
    path(r'teams/<int:team_id>/)', views.get_team_formation, name='get_team_formation'),

    path(r'game-instance/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_match_instance, name='get_match_instance'),

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Now if I go to 0.0.0.0:8000/backend/game-instance/1/ I get that the url does not exist.
What's wrong?

Comment: still doesn't work. all this file it's "under" backend

Comment: What does your views file look like ? What about the project's base urls.py ?

Comment: could you also please post the main `urls.py` file which resides alongside `settings.py`?

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('backend/', include('backend.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: Are you getting a `404`? Did you set `Debug=True` in `settings.py`? Would help if you update the post with exact error message.

Comment: The current path, backend/game-instance/1/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: backend/ game-instance/<int:game_id>/) [name='get_match_instance']

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 0.0.0.0:8000?

I would try something like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/game-instance/1/
Or maybe it's http://127.0.0.1:8000/game-instance/1/

You have 2 urls.py file right? One of them point to the other one. The urls.py file inside the same folder with settings.py should point to the urls.py file inside your backend folder.

```
 re_path('any_name_you_want/', include('backend.urls')),
```

Then inside your backend/urls.py you should have the structure urls you linked above.
Not sure if it helped XD.

Comment: But it's like you said :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your views.py, can you post the code referenced by the url game-instance? Are the others urls working or only this one is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the urls.py which you posted are the project urls and you don't have separate urls for the backend.

So your endpoints look like this at the moment:

```
0.0.0.0:8000/game-instance/<id>
0.0.0.0:8000/reports/<id>
0.0.0.0:8000/teams/<id>
```

If you want to have these endpoints with `backend`, you need to explicitly add it to the urls.py, like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'backend/reports/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_pdf_report, name='get_pdf_report'),
    path(r'backend/teams/<int:team_id>/)', views.get_team_formation, name='get_team_formation'),

    path(r'backend/game-instance/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_match_instance, name='get_match_instance'),

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Or another approach is to create another urls.py for your backend in your backend app and include it in your project's urls.py:

Your backend/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'reports/<int:game_id>/', views.get_pdf_report, name='get_pdf_report'),
    path(r'teams/<int:team_id>/', views.get_team_formation, name='get_team_formation'),

   path(r'game-instance/<int:game_id>/', views.get_match_instance, name='get_match_instance'),

]
```

And include in project's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'backend/', include('backend.urls'),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Both of this solutions would create the endpoints like your'd like

Comment: Thank, I've already two urls file like you said. One in the folder where settings.py is, and the other one in the "backend" application.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. Infamous like a forgotten semicolumn.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'reports/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_pdf_report, name='get_pdf_report'),
    path(r'teams/<int:team_id>/)', views.get_team_formation, name='get_team_formation'),

    path(r'game-instance/<int:game_id>/)', views.get_match_instance, name='get_match_instance'),

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Do you see the forgotten, and unexplainable brackets? Just at the end of the url pattern?!